# What is the "book of the law" mentioned in Joshua 1?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pentateuch-chumash, joshua--book-of

Specifically, Joshua 1:8:

> **[Joshua 1:8 (JPS)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0601.htm#8)**
>
> <sup>8</sup>  This book of the law shall not depart out of thy mouth, but thou shalt meditate therein day and night, that thou mayest observe to do according to all that is written therein; for then thou shalt make thy ways prosperous, and then thou shalt have good success.

What is this "book of the law" that God refers to here? Is it the Pentateuch?

Answer (score 13):

[Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) understands it to be referring specifically to the Book of Deuteronomy.

[Metzodot David](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA) understands that it refers to the Law mentioned in [the previous verse](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0601.htm#7) which the [Malbim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) explicitly states refers to the entire Pentateuch. The [Targum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Jonathan) also implies that and I think it is the most straightforward read of the verses.

Answer (score 10):

[Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14264&st=&pgnum=8) translates this as Deuteronomy (Devarim).

Comment: Oooooo 8 seconds!

Answer (score 10):

Even if as the others noted the actual book referred to is Deuteronomy or even all five books of the Pentateuch, the [Talmud (Menachot 99B)](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=99b&format=pdf) understands the reference to refer at least symbolically to everything which is considered Torah.

Comment: This is not so clear from Menachot. Could you quote the passage that you think is a proof text?